# Frobenius norm bounds on exponentials of anti-Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, quantum-mechanics, norms

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two anti-Hermitian matrices satisifying $\|X\|, \|Y\| \leq \pi$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the spectral norm. I'm trying to prove the following bounds on the Frobenius norm of the exponential of them ($e^X, e^Y$ are unitary matrices). Namely,
$$
c\|X-Y\|_F \leq \|e^X-e^Y\|_F \leq \|X-Y\|_F,
$$
where $c$ is some dimension independent constant, which I believe should be $\frac{2}{\pi}$, but any other constant is okay. And I also suspect (from numerics) that this holds for any unitary invariant norm, not just $\|\cdot\|_F$.

The upper bound follows from triangle inequality over a telescoping sum, which is already figured out:
$$
\|e^X-e^Y\|_F \leq \sum_{k=1}^m \|e^{(k-1)X/m}(e^{X/m}-e^{Y/m})e^{(m-k)Y/m}\| = m \|e^{X/m}-e^{Y/m}\|_F,
$$
and by taking $m \to \infty$ we have the upper bound.

My question is mainly on the lower bound, which I don't know how to prove. The special case when $X$ and $Y$ commute is easy, because it reduces to proving
$$
c\|X\|_F\leq \|e^X-I\|_F.
$$
Then we can analyze the eigenvalues directly. Suppose the eigenvalues of $X$ are $i\theta_k$, with $|\theta_k|\leq \pi$. Then for each $\theta_k$, one can prove that
$$
|e^{i\theta_k}-1|^2 = 4\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta_k}{2} \right) \geq \frac{4}{\pi^2}\theta_k^2.
$$
Thus we have
$$
\frac{2}{\pi}\|X\|_F\leq \|e^X-I\|_F.
$$
But how to lift this argument to non-commuting $X$ and $Y$ is not clear.

To verify this, I have also generated some random 2-dimensional $X$ and $Y$, and compute the corresponding norms. The [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbHyD.png) seems to agree with the analysis.

Meanwhile, it is known from Eq. (D3) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04378) that if $\|X\|, \|Y\|\leq r$, then one has the lower bound with $c=2-e^r$. But this is too loose for my purposes. In particular, I would need a lower bound for $\|X\|, \|Y\|\leq \pi$.

Any suggestion is very appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to reduce to $Y=I$ in the commuting case, I think you will need $\| X\|, \|Y\|$ to be less than $\pi/2$ rather than $\pi$, in order that $\|X-Y\|$ remains bounded by $\pi$.

Comment: @TerryTao Yeah, something is fishy. If all eigenvalues are $\pm i\pi$, we should get $e^X=e^Y=-I$ pretty much independently of what $X,Y$ are, so we seem to need to be at least a bit below $\pi$ to get anything. Let's wait until the OP clarifies...

Comment: @fedja Thanks for the comments. You are right that when the eigenvalues are all close to $\pm i\pi$, the lower bound clearly does not hold. I'll try to fix the question soon.

Comment: @HaimengZhao OK. Ping me when you figure out what exactly you need :-)